# ffmpeg, vlc - Unable to find input stream

Tags: vlc-media-player, ffmpeg, streaming

Good day to all... I have some "little" problems with ffserver and ffmpeg...

What I need to do is to broadcast a live video. So I got the cam... used vlc and used send stream option. I sent it to 192.168.1.9:64555, which is a virtual machine on the same computer, running centos.

On the virtual machine I run the command ffmpeg -i 192.168.1.9:64555 output.mpg.

The response is "unable to find file whatever".

Can any1 tell me what I did wrong?

Thank you and have a great day.

Print-screen with error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFmpeg uses the [file protocol](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#SEC44) for a resource if a protocol is not specified. Since your input resource (192.168.1.9:65444) has no protocol attached, it is being treated as a filename.

Figure out what protocol VLC is streaming with and reformat your input resource to look like the specification given in FFmpeg's [list of protocols](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#TOC42). It will probably look something like

```
ffmpeg -i protocol://192.168.1.9:65444 output.mpg
```

Comment: Just to expand on lewist's correct answer, possible protocols would include http and rtsp.

Answer (score 0):

According to ffmpeg's help output (ffmpeg -h):

```
 -i filename         input file name
```

This means that after the -i switch, ffmpeg expects to find the file, not the address.
So the right syntax would be:

```
 ffmpeg -i output.mpeg 192.168.1.9:64555
```

Comment: Except that -i expects the **input** file name, and output.mpeg is clearly the output file.

Comment: Oh, now I get what he wanted to do. You are right. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: My last comment was rude. Sorry, +1 for putting up with that.